# What is the [natural] tag for?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is a [natural] tag with [one question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural) (so far).

Not sure what the tag is or could be for.  Maybe worth deleting?

Comment: Man, that is a stumper!